# Xml deserialization error from Goodreads API (System.InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, api, xml-deserialization

I am building an application using the goodreads api. I ran the following URI:
**https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=Mykey&title=pride%20and%20prejudice**

and obtained the Xml document:

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
<Request>
<authentication>true</authentication>
<key>
<![CDATA[ MyKey ]]>
</key>
<method>
<![CDATA[ book_title ]]>
</method>
</Request>
<book>
.....
</book>
</GoodreadsResponse>
```

Then I copied the document and did a special paste(Paste as xml classes) to generate a model.

I wrote a service class for the model as follows:

```
   public class RecommendationService
{
    public static async Task<Models.RecommendationItem.GoodreadsResponse> GetRecommendationInfo(string title)
    {
        string uri = $"https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=my key&title={title}";
        var bookItem = new Models.RecommendationItem.GoodreadsResponse();

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Models.RecommendationItem.GoodreadsResponse));
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            bookItem = (Models.RecommendationItem.GoodreadsResponse)serializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());
            bookItem.book.title = bookItem.book.title ?? "FAIL";

        }
        return bookItem;
    }
```

This code worked like a charm when I ran it for the title "pride and prejudice" but when I run for the the title "fire and ice", I get the error(with stack trace):

System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (10, 4). ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16.\r\n   at System.UInt16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToUInt16(String s)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderGoodreadsResponse.Read31_GoodreadsResponseBook(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderGoodreadsResponse.Read32_GoodreadsResponse(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderGoodreadsResponse.Read33_GoodreadsResponse()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)\r\n   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)\r\n   at CystaTLB.Services.RecommendationService.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Sravani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CystaTLB\CystaTLB\Services\RecommendationService.cs:line 27\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at CystaTLB.CystaLuisDialog.<RB>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\Sravani\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\CystaTLB\\CystaTLB\\CystaLuisDialog.cs:line 200\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.d__21`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.d__2`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at CystaTLB.MessagesController.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Sravani\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CystaTLB\CystaTLB\Controllers\MessagesController.cs:line 31"

What am I doing wrong??
Is there a way I can resolve this??

Comment: On row 10 of xml you have a number that is larger than 16 bits and you are trying to put into a class object that is declared as a short.

Comment: Thanks A LOT!! That really saved me..

Comment: but... but... but... that's exactly what the exception message already told you! "There is an error in XML document (10, 4)." = look at line 10, column 4; "System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16." - it doesn't fit in a `ushort`